# interchangeable IDs for login under PCI DSS like Facebook and Twitter

Tags: pci-dss, facebook, identity, twitter

Is using multiple interchangeable IDs a PCI DSS complaint? Facebook and Twitter uses the same method for sign in.
multiple interchangeable IDs such as sign in with email or mobile or username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in PCI DSS that prevents you allowing users to login with multiple IDs (such as their email address or their phone number) - just make sure that you apply the same security controls regardless of which type of ID they use.

Comment: I was stopped by this PCI DSS 8 v3.2: `Assigning a unique identification (ID) to each person with access ensures that actions taken on critical
data and systems are performed by, and can be traced to, known and authorized users.`. seemed that a unique means that only 1 unique, but it can be interpreted to both as a unique ID in field and a unique ID in total.

Comment: @HM107 They key point of that requirement is that it it allows you to tie any action to an individual user (i.e, that there are no account shared between users), so that you have accountability. It doesn't mean that users can't have more than one account (which the often should due to privilege separation), or that a single account can't allow you to login with either the username or email address.

Comment: @HM107 and BTW, from March 2024 you'll need to be aligning to PCI DSSv4, so you should probably be looking at that rather than 3.2 (although in this case the requirement is the same).